# PHP format date with milliseconds works but parse fails

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using the following format `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z` to follow the JavaScript `toISOString` implementation (2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z).

Everything works fine if I have a `DateTime` and I want to format it, however I cannot parse a string that uses this format.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z';
$stringDateTime = (new \DateTime())->format($format);
var_dump(date_create_from_format($format,$stringDateTime));
```

I'm using PHP 7 and I have tested the code above with PHP 7.0,7.1 and 7.2. The return that I expect in line 3 is a `DateTime` class, however I'm getting a `false` due to there is a parse problem.

I hope someone can clarify this behavior.
Thanks

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that the `v` format modifier doesn't work with `DateTime::createFromFormat`. Unfortunately, not all of them do.

Comment: Also `Z` is the timezone, not a static part of the format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Datetime will handle it fine, you won't need to create from format.

```
<?php
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z';
$stringDateTime = (new \DateTime())->format($format);
var_dump(date_create($stringDateTime));
```

https://3v4l.org/phLE1

**Result:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-03-13 18:07:30.005000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

This also works:

```
<?php
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z';
$stringDateTime = (new \DateTime())->format($format);
var_dump(date_create_from_format($format, $stringDateTime));

$format = \DateTime::ISO8601;
$stringDateTime = (new \DateTime())->format($format);
var_dump(date_create_from_format($format, $stringDateTime));
```

https://3v4l.org/FcUqe

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-03-13 18:15:10.011717"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-03-13 18:15:10.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+01:00"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem that I have is that I'm using a library where I have to choose a format for ``DateTime`` for both, format and parse and that format needs to be exactly equals to 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z because it's the format defined in the documentation.

Comment: Is it warranted that this particular format is supported in the constructor? I'm having the same problem and wanted to use an explicit format because it avoids any ambiguity, but failed because of the miliseconds bug.

Comment: @Alejandro You can use any input format which is supported by [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), and the same format parameters for output format. e.g [DateTime::format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But how would the function know **which** format am I using if it just receives a string with a date? `createFromFormat` solves this by requiring the format too, but how does the constructor do?

Comment: If you mean the value you pass directly to `new \DateTime('the value')` then internally php will do its best to parse it. https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/date When you do createFromFormat your supplying a constraint, which fails if its not in that format.